# MySQL: Select products of any given category

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to improve performance in a query that involves getting all products that belongs to any of a list of categories:

```
CREATE TABLE `shop_products` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `slug` varchar(125) NOT NULL,
  `on_sale` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `created_date` (`created_date`),
  KEY `slug` (`slug`),
  KEY `updated_date` (`updated_date`),
  KEY `on_sale_deleted` (`on_sale`,`deleted`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `shop_product_terms` (
  `product_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `term_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `term_id` (`term_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Selecting those products (not deleted and on sale) that belongs to any of a given list of categories:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM shop_products AS p
INNER JOIN shop_product_terms AS pt ON p.id=pt.product_id
WHERE
(pt.term_id=93 OR pt.term_id=97) AND 
p.on_sale=1 AND p.deleted IS NULL 
ORDER BY created_date DESC, updated_date DESC LIMIT 55, 10
```

It is currently taking 0.1 sec to execute. Calling `EXPLAIN`:

```
id  select_type table  partitions   type    possible_keys   key     key_len    ref                  rows   Extra
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   SIMPLE      pt      NULL        range   term_id         term_id     4       NULL                362     Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      p       NULL        eq_ref  PRIMARY,on_sale PRIMARY     8       pt.product_id     1       Using where
```

I'm noticing that the `(pt.term_id=93 OR pt.term_id=97)` part is what it is slowing down the query (type=range because of the OR I guess).

Is there any way I can rewrite this query to improve something here?

---

Edit: EXPLAIN result of alternative query proposed by @Alex

```
id  select_type     table               partitions  type        possible_keys           key?    key_len?    ref?            rows?   Extra?
1   PRIMARY         <derived2>          NULL        ALL         NULL                    NULL    NULL        NULL            363     Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY         p                   NULL        eq_ref      PRIMARY,on_sale_deleted PRIMARY 8           pt.product_id   1       Using where
2   DERIVED         shop_product_terms  NULL        range       term_id                 term_id 4           NULL            362     Using where
```

---

Second Edit:

```
id  select_type         table               partitions          type    possible_keys       key?            key_len?    ref?            rows?   Extra?
1   PRIMARY             p                   NULL                ref     on_sale_deleted     on_sale_deleted 3           const,const     3502    Using where; Using filesort
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  shop_product_terms  NULL                range   term_id             term_id         4           NULL            362     Using where
```

Comment: show us your `CREATE TABLE` for both tables please

Comment: Done @Alex, I've removed fields not being used in this query to simplify it

Answer (score 0):

You've to check if this is really faster.

```
SELECT p.id
FROM shop_products AS p
INNER JOIN shop_product_terms AS pt ON p.id=pt.product_id
WHERE
pt.term_id IN (93, 97) AND 
p.on_sale=1 AND p.deleted IS NULL 
ORDER BY created_date DESC, updated_date DESC LIMIT 55, 10
```

Comment: No it does not, exactly the same.

Comment: :/ Sorry, worth a try (I guess).

Comment: This is the exact same query (as EXPLAIN EXTENDED followed by SHOW WARNINGS would prove)

Answer (score 0):

Just to improve performance a little you can:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM shop_products as p
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT
     product_id
   FROM
     shop_product_terms 
   WHERE term_id IN (93,97)
) AS pt 
ON p.id=pt.product_id
WHERE
p.on_sale=1 AND p.deleted IS NULL 
ORDER BY created_date DESC, updated_date DESC LIMIT 55, 10
```

**EDIT** since you posted explain statement for me we can try this way:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM shop_products AS p
WHERE
p.id IN (SELECT 
     product_id
   FROM
     shop_product_terms 
   WHERE term_id IN (93,97)
)
AND 
p.on_sale=1 AND p.deleted IS NULL 
ORDER BY created_date DESC, updated_date DESC LIMIT 55, 10
```

Comment: Yes, ´term_id´ is already an index, see CREATE statement, and EXPLAIN shows it is being used

Comment: @RaúlFerràs did you try my query?

Comment: Yes but did not see any improvement :(

Comment: @RaúlFerràs and same explain? How long it takes just to run subquery **SELECT
     product_id
   FROM
     shop_product_terms 
   WHERE term_id IN (93,97)** ?

Comment: It takes 0.040s. There's like 25,000 registers in that table. Here is the EXPLAIN of the full query http://pastebin.com/82ehWqY8

Comment: @RaúlFerràs I can't open the link you've sent. try to add image in your original post please

Comment: Added the EXPLAIN result to the question.

Comment: I'm not (yet) convinced that this query affords any improvement. Can you explain why you think it does?

Comment: I was feeling like it was performing slow and so wondering if there was a better way to define that query.